# Table constructor toolbar is unavailable in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I begin to study databases for my C# projects, but I can't add relationship between two tables. I can't understand why Table Constructor toolbar is unavailable.

[Link to screenshot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451056/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%B2-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that this tool isn't supported any more in Visual Studio 2013 and higher.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5a4ezk9.aspx